# "Add an item to a list" using rule just works for plain text

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I created a rule with an action which "Add an item to a list".
The value of the item to add is this (also see my picture bellow)

```
Voucher: [node:title].
The code for this voucher is [codigo-otorgado:value].
View the voucher: [node:url]
```

This item will be added to a field of the user which I created at `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` The details of this field are:

```
Name: My voucher codes
Type: Long text
Widget: Text area (multiple rows)
Text processing: Plain Text 
Number of values: Unlimited
```

So far so good. When the rule is fired all is working right, but The problem is that the text is shown as plain text. As you can see there is a url and breaks lines that I need to print out.

I guess the first suggestion will be to change the **Text processing** of the field  to **Filtered Html or Full Html**, and so I did.

But then the tokens ([node:url], [node:title]..) inside the value doesn't work. The tokens are printed as it, instead of their values.

I know that **Rules** is very mature module and I'm sure there must be a way to do this. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have saved your textarea field as Plain text, change it to Filtered Text (in Text formats admin settings you should check allowed tags):
[image]

Comment: Ok, I get the select list to change to Full Html. I works, but tokens are not working in this format. I found the token filter module which is useful to get global tokens but is not useful for node tokens like [node:url]

Comment: Please try next module then: http://drupal.org/project/token_insert